# Conditional 301 redirect depending on server (localhost vs production)

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, 301-redirect

By practise I do a 301 redirect non-www -> www for my production server deployments.  But I have a little annoying problem/discrepency with the .htaccess rewrite settings between my development server & the production server.

If I leave the non-www -> www 301 redirect condition in the .htaccess file (which gets deployed with the website) my development webserver tries to redirect "http://localhost/mysite" to "http://www.localhost/mysite" which doesn't work.

So I have to switch between .htaccess rewrite conditions depending on the server, and this is a little cumbersome.

Is there any way of using a conditional statement to achieve something like...

```
# Rewrite "www.domain.com -> domain.com" 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <If !localhost>         #This is not valid code
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
  <else>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
  </If>
</IfModule>
```

Or is there a smarter way around this?

Looking forward to your ideas.  Thank you very much.
Prembo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your config intends to remove a `www` from `localhost` requests, if I'm understanding that right?  That part shouldn't be necessary, so let me know if I'm missing something.

How about something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion. I tried it. When I try to access the URL  or IP address of LAN with a port number or directory (eg. http://localhost:2222/subdir or http://192.168.100.10:2222/subdir) , it prepended the www, so I added the following conditions...
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost.*$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^192.168.2\..*$ [NC]

Do you forsee any side-effects from these conditions? It seems to work.

Thanks again...